# SQLAlchemy complex query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Today I'm facing a problem with an sqlalchemy query. I've tried for a while now but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I'm quite new to this whole story of sqlalchemy, I've started to become comfortable with medium-simple queries, but I can't solve the following one:

```
units = Unit.query.join(Campaign).join(ServedUnitMetric, and_(ServedUnitMetric.client_id == clientID)).filter(
            (Campaign.active_applications.any(and_(ActiveApplication.application_id == client.application_id, ActiveApplication.enabled == True)))                    &
            (Campaign.targeting_setting.has(TargetingSetting.countries.any(and_(Country.country_code == client.locale.country_code, Country.is_active == True))))     &
            (Campaign.expiration_date > datetime.utcnow())                                                                                                            &
            (Campaign.active_campaign.has(ActiveCampaign.expenses + item.price <= Campaign.budget))                                                                   &
            (Campaign.active_campaign.has(ActiveCampaign.status == CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ACTIVE))                                                                           &
            (Campaign.max_bid >= item.price)                                                                                                                          &
            (Unit.serve_setting.has(and_(ServeSetting.language_code == client.locale.language_code, ServeSetting.valid_from <= datetime.utcnow(), ServeSetting.valid_to >= datetime.utcnow()))) &

        (
            ((Unit.serve_setting.has(ServeSetting.serve_once_per_period == True)) &  (ServedUnitMetric.unit_id != Unit.id))                                         |
            ((Unit.serve_setting.has(ServeSetting.serve_once_per_period == True)) &  (ServedUnitMetric.unit_id == Unit.id) & (datetime.utcnow() > (ServedUnitMetric.endDate + ServeSetting.period_hours)))
        )
        )
```

The first part of the query is working, now I'm trying to get the second part working but I've still got an issue. 
It always returns empty data, but I've prepared tests and I'm sure that it should return data.

I got the error but I still don't know how to solve it. The problem lays here

> ServedUnitMetric.endDate + ServeSetting.period_hours

it look like SQLAlchemy is not translating **DateTime + Interval** properly. It look this sentence is translated to a double value. Now is all about understanding how I can add a DateTime to an Interval and the trick should be done. 
I'm trying with **func.adddate** but it goes on overflow, I imagine is due Interval being 1970-1-1 + the interval you input.

I've finally founded a solution that seems working, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236032/956541

so that line become:

> ((Unit.serve_setting.has(ServeSetting.serve_once_per_period == True))
>   &  (ServedUnitMetric.unit_id == Unit.id) &
>   (func.abs(func.unix_timestamp(datetime.utcnow()) -
>   func.unix_timestamp(ServedUnitMetric.endDate)) >=
>   (ServeSetting.period_hours * 60 * 60)))

Thanks for your help,

Enrico

Comment: I'd suggest to take a look at generated SQL and see if it makes sense. Without model definitions, sample data and expected output it's hard to tell what's wrong here.

Comment: Indeed, take a look at generated `SQL` statement. I assume that your expression with `.period_hours` is not translated properly in `mysql`. The solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13566537/99594) might help.

Comment: Hey Audrius, thanks for your usggestion I've enabled sqlachemy logging and I'm trying to figure out what's wrong. I'll give it a try and if I can't find a solution I'll update the post.

Comment: Thanks also to van :D I'm going to try your solution straight away

Comment: If you found the solution, instead of editing the question it would be better to post it as an answer and accept it, so that others having a similar problem could see that it was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is func.timestamp(date)

```
((Unit.serve_setting.has(ServeSetting.serve_once_per_period == True)) & (ServedUnitMetric.unit_id == Unit.id) & (func.abs(func.unix_timestamp(datetime.utcnow()) - func.unix_timestamp(ServedUnitMetric.endDate)) >= (ServeSetting.period_hours * 60 * 60)))
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236032/956541